# How to forced cancel BeginExecuteXmlReader() executing

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

What is the best way to forced cancel query executing which has been started via BeginExecuteXmlReader() method of SqlCommand class on some timeout?

Tnank you.

Comment: By setting a [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)?

Comment: "The CommandTimeout property will be ignored during asynchronous method calls such as BeginExecuteReader." [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

Comment: There is a `Cancel` method on the `SqlCommand`. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx) says that it will attempt to cancel the execution of the command. Using a `WaitHandle` with a timeout on the Wait call you can possibly call cancel on the command.

Comment: @PHeiberg Thank you for your suggestions. I've already implemented the same approach.